# How do i upgrade my android target API in Meteor

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

I am building an android app with Meteor/Cordova. My meteor is currently version 1.5, Cordova 4.3.0. My default build uses API 25 but when I try to submit my APK to the play store, I get this message:

```
Your app currently targets API level 25 and must target at least API level 26 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 26
```

.

How do I upgrade to API level 26?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside mobile-config.js add

```
App.setPreference('android-targetSdkVersion', '26');
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to gradle, and search for *targetSdkVersion = 25* . Change it to use android *targetSdkVersion = 26*